# Best way to validate two dates (Date Start and Date End)

Tags: sql-server, validation, date

Hi have a table in SQL SERVER and it contains `Date Start` and `Date End`
How can I know if the inserted date does not exist in the table.

Example :

`01-Jan-15` to `15-Jan-15` is inserted to table

`01-Mar-15` to `15-Mar-15` is inserted to table

`01-Feb-15` and `15-Feb-15` is valid because it is not in the range.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the table from containing overlapping date ranges? Or are you just trying to prevent duplicates in general?

Comment: What do you mean by validating 2-01-15 and 2-15-15?

Comment: i want to prevent overlapping date ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlapping inserts can be prevented with some `WHERE NOT EXISTS(...BETWEEN...)` logic, as in the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DateIns(@DateStart DATE, @DateEnd DATE)
AS
INSERT Dates(DateStart, DateEnd) 
SELECT @DateStart, @DateEnd
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM Dates
  WHERE @DateStart BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd
  OR @DateEnd BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd
);
```

The following fiddle demonstrates the procedure accepting three valid ranges and rejecting one invalid range: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fc6e/5

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2015-02-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2015-02-15';

SELECT COUNT(1) c
FROM YourTable t
WHERE StartDate < @EndDate AND EndDate > @StartDate
```

`c` should be 0 if there's no overlap. That's all you need to do. Use `>=` and `<=` if you count the same day as being an overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I would take:

1. Create a user-defined function (UDF) to count the number of overlaps in your table
2. Add this UDF as a check contraint on your table. This prevents inserts of overlapping dates

The details are described below. The following table is my sample table I used.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dates](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Dates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then, I created the user defined function (UDF).

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_CountOverlaps (
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE
) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Rows INT = (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Dates D
        WHERE (D.EndDate IS NULL OR @StartDate IS NULL OR @StartDate <= D.EndDate)
            AND (D.StartDate IS NULL OR @EndDate IS NULL OR @EndDate >= D.StartDate)
    )
    RETURN COALESCE(@Rows, 1)
END
GO
```

Finally, I added the user defined function to a check constraint on the table. Note that you have to check that your function checks that the row count is 1 (not 0). This is because your constraint runs after the insert is made, but before the insert is committed to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Dates
    ADD CONSTRAINT chkOverlaps CHECK (dbo.f_CountOverlaps(StartDate, EndDate) = 1 );
```

Then, I tested this with inserts.

```
INSERT dbo.Dates VALUES ('1/1/2015', '1/1/2015') -- Good
INSERT dbo.Dates VALUES ('3/1/2015', '3/1/2015') -- Good
INSERT dbo.Dates VALUES ('2/1/2015', '2/1/2015') -- Good
INSERT dbo.Dates VALUES ('2/1/2015', '2/1/2015') -- Bad, dupe
INSERT dbo.Dates VALUES ('2/28/2015', '3/2/2015') -- Bad, overlap
```

The "bad" inserts throw an error message due to the check contraints:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 42
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkOverlaps". The conflict occurred in database "SampleDB", table "dbo.Dates".
```

Finally, checking the content of the table shows only my "good" inserts were allowed:

```
Id          StartDate               EndDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
3           2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

The between function should work. Try `Select 1 from yourTable where yourDate is between 'date start' and 'date end'`